# Dynamic linq against entity not in dbml

Tags: linq-to-sql, expression-trees, dynamic-linq

I have been asked to investigate the usefulness of linq to sql for a reporting application we are building. Our reporting table is a sql server wide table with many thousands of columns of different types (String1-500, Int1-500 etc). It holds the results from dynamic reports constructed by the user.

We have a second table that maps a report field to a column on the reporting table with a type ordinal pair (i.e. column String1).

I know it should be possible to construct expression trees against a linq to sql dbml class that can return the report results. I would like to take this a bit further and return only the columns that map to fields and return a dynamic type as the result.

Also to avoid maintaining the huge reporting table class in the dbml.

**Is it possible to run a dynamic linq query against a table not in the dbml, i.e. (not a linq to sql entity)?**

I realise this is a bastardisation of L2S and I am not fond of it. I am considering using plain old ADO and returning an untype result set.

Many thanks,

Ian

Comment: Edited. Sorry I was rambling.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to run LINQ to SQL against an entity not in the DBML.

There may be several ways of doing this but the simplest I can think of is calling [DataContext.ExecuteQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb361109.aspx) which will execute a SQL statement and return a result set.

If you know the type of result you can cast it into an object, otherwise you can return it as a list of Object types.